# Linker error while building libevent project

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have one project which uses libevent libraries and i am compiling it VS2017. It runs in linux perfectly. I am getting errors like below:

```
1>ftpcmd.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol evutil_snprintf referenced in function do_client_read
1>ftpcmd.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol evutil_inet_pton referenced in function handle_pasv
1>ftpdata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol evutil_inet_pton
1>ftpcmd.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol bufferevent_free referenced in function fs_client_free
1>ftpdata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol bufferevent_free
```

Does anyone know how to link libevent with project? I read some question related to that and they say i need to compile libevent using VS commad prompt. I tried that with `nmake -f Makefile.nmake` libevent-2.1.8-stable but it failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to add `-levent` to the options?

Comment: what options..?

Comment: did you try to link to libevent built using CMake for Windows, like suggested here: https://github.com/libevent/libevent#cmake-windows-1 ?

Comment: Well, I have a project which uses libevent library. Libevent, libevent_core, libevent_extra. I am trying to compile myproject.sln and getting above errors. If i follow instructions for tha link. I will have two sln files and i dont know how that supposed to work? @EwaAr

Comment: when you follow the instruction above, you will get projects and solution files in the location .../libevent-release-2.1.8-stable/build/*. Than open libevent.sln in VS and build it. If it build successfully, you will get 3 static libraries in location ...//libevent-release-2.1.8-stable/build/lib/<DEBUG or RELEASE>/*.lib (event.lib, event_core.lib, event_extra.lib). Than you have to open myproject.sln in VS, in Solution Explorer find the project that you want to link event.lib to, right-click to Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, add libevent libraries.

Comment: Than in Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories add location of libevent libraries.

Comment: Thank you for explaining so clearly. But thing is, i already have those build library available so can't i use those directly without compiling again? @EwaAr

Comment: it depends on what compiler was used to build them, since many compilers are mutually incompatible. If you build both libraries and your project with the same toolchain, it should not be problem. Also, you may check if you include right libevent headers and function declaration match definition

Comment: @EwaAr i compiled libevent but there is no folder created in build. Project.sln has been created instead of libevent.sln. What am i doing wrong?